# Contact details layout xml

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to find out the layout XML for contact details (regardless if it's AOSP, Samsung's, HTC's or othe vendor). However I'm struggling to find the xml that I want to reuse. Below you'll find a image of what I'm actually looking for. I found a link for AOSP layout xml https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/master/res/layout but cannot find the right one.

[image: ut]

Answer (score 0):

On principle you have unique and multiple informations on user. Unique data are birthday (no user has multiple birthdays ;-) ), id and so on. But a user can have multiple mail-addresses, phone numbers and so one. This thoughts should be in the centre of design decision. So you can do following for example:

```
<user id="any_unique_id">
        <surename>Surename</surename>
        <birthday>1994/10/10</birthday>

        <mail-contacts>
                <mail type="private">mail@example.com</mail>
                <mail type="work">mail@test.com</mail>

                <!-- Add all mail adresses you need an think a bout the type attributes you need-->
        </mail-contacts>

        <phone-contacts>
                <phone type="mobile">012222222</phone>
                <phone type="business">34343487</phone>

                <!-- Add all phone contacts you need  an think a bout the type attributes you need-->
        </phone-contacts>       
</user>
```